# Using the same player when I connect to a local phone server from a different device?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend has Minecraft PE v0.14.1 installed on her (Samsung) Android phone, and has a nice world she built, so we decided to play together.

I have Minecraft PE v0.14.1 under Bluestacks, and the same version on my Blackberry Z10 (which emulates Android v4.3, and yes, Minecraft PE works - just a bit slower).

I couldn't connect to her world automatically through LAN, ended up adding her phone wifi IP as a server, reset the router, and everything worked. I named my character "Charlie Brown", and played for some time.

Then we stopped for a while, and I decided I wanted to play through my Z10 this time. I connected, but forgot to change my player name, so I was spawned at the world's spawn point (the same when I began at the emulator). However, as my Charlie Brown character, I had built lots of things, had many items, and was inside my house. So I did not want to have to restart.

But when I changed my player name on the Z10 to "Charlie Brown", I connected and... same thing - it spawned me at the world's spawn point, no items, nothing. It still seems to be treating me as a "new" player.

So, my question is: **how do I use the same "player" as I was using on the other "device"?** My new player has already slept at a bed inside the house. Interestingly, when we stopped and restarted several times, I found everything still worked when playing from Bluestacks.

I emphasize we're not using a local Minecraft PE server, or anything like that. I just used what the app offers: her phone as the world's server. How do I use the **same player** as before when connecting from different devices? I also always try and connect to her phone, since she was always the host, and the world we play is located there.

Comment: It would seem as the player data is stored locally on the device. If that's the case, i don't see a way to play on the same player from 2 different devices.

Comment: Yeah, I figured something like that. It happened that I reinstalled Bluestacks, and it didn't maintain my old data as requested. After reinstalling all apps, I still had no problem informing the same user name and the "server" phone recognizing me. Still wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some time, I figured out how to do it - pretty simple, may I say. So, if you have more than one device that you want to use as clients that connect using the *same identity*, you need to change the Minecraft PE client ID on the devices you want. This client ID is contained within the `clientId.txt` file.

Let the "server" alone, you don't need to mess with it for this.

Under Android, `clientId.txt` is in the `/sdcard/games/com.mojang/minecraftpe` folder. You just need to open the file on the 2nd device, replace the ID inside by the ID you found on the same file from the 1st device and you're ready to go. Any server, from now on, will recognize both devices as the same player. You can play on a device, leave the world, connect again with the other device and you'll be at the same point (with same items, XP, etc.) where you last left.

It's important to know that you CAN have different names, if you wish. It's the client ID that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a 100% complete answer, but as RustyMembers said, your account data (with the user id and everything) is normally to be stored on your phone's internal memory.

If that's the case you'll have to search where your emulator stores the data  of Minecraft's local data and copy it over to Bluestacks.
I can't give a complete answer as I don't own Minecraft for Android nor do I have experience with any of those emulators.

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway. As I replied to him, I'm almost discarding this local storage hypothesis completely, as I reinstalled Bluestacks 2, and it still connected me okay. Well, will have to keep on locally testing what it might be.

Comment: Reinstalling the software doesn't mean that your settings are getting wiped. (Normally programs store their settings in %APPDATA% under Windows.)
I'm almost sure that it's stored somewhere and that reinstalling bluestacks doesn't affect that data. However you can copy the files from the emulator to a location on your HD you know.
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102377/where-are-the-game-save-files-located-in-pc

Comment: I forgot to be more clear: BlueStacks gives you the option to wipe your data off when uninstalling, and although I chose "don't", it did. :-( I had to install and setup every app (obviously, including MCPE) I wanted to use again. Anyway what you said IS pretty important in this scenario, sorry for not making that clear previously.